# SVG radial gradients - moving focal point (center)

Tags: svg

I'm studying SVG now and got stuck at Radial gradients topic, on moving radial gradient center exactly. Let's say, I have 2 gradient examples ([codepen snippet to play around](https://codepen.io/nat-davydova/pen/e52d13f5700b11a954ef70b73a76b7e1)). A basic one (works perfectly):

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:lang="en"xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
       <title>Bulls-eye Repeating Radial Gradient</title>
       <radialGradient id="bullseye"cx="50%" cy="50%" r="10%" spreadMethod="repeat">
         <stop stop-color="tomato" offset="50%"/>
         <stop stop-color="#222" offset="50%"/>
      </radialGradient>
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" rx="10%"fill="url(#bullseye)"/>
    </svg>
```

and an example where I'm trying to apply `fx` and `fy` attributes to move gradient focal point:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:lang="en"xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
   <title>Bulls-eye Repeating Radial Gradient</title>
   <radialGradient id="bullseye2" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="10%" fx=".2" fy=".2"  spreadMethod="repeat">
     <stop stop-color="tomato" offset="50%"/>
     <stop stop-color="#222" offset="50%"/>
  </radialGradient>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" rx="10%"fill="url(#bullseye2)"/>
</svg>
```

Here it somehow just cut a piece of shape instead of just moving a center point.

Could you please explain what am I doing wrong here and why it works in a such strange way?

Comment: You moved the focal point outside the defining radius. Try it with `.45` for both x and y, for example, to see it behave more as you expected

Comment: Once you've played with more reasonable values a bit, you should be able to see why it did the behaviour you see here, but if you're still confused, try turning off the repeat and that should help.

Comment: @Dave and I'm still interested which values here are reasonable and why. I've tried to google how it works and why some gradients accept these numbers (for example, a book I'm using to study SVG) and some - don't and just couldn't find an info. That's why I've posted the question.

Comment: @Dave and if you understand how it all works, could you please add an answer with a bit more info?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two main concepts when defining a radial gradient:

- The point where the gradient begins ("focal point")
- The ellipse which defines the "outer" shape of the gradient

I'll mention the "repeat" option later, but for now: The gradient is rendered from the focal point outwards until it reaches the outer shape. Maybe it helps to imagine the outer shape shrinking until it reaches the focal point.

This means that if the focal point is *inside* the defined shape, it will appear fairly intuitive:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="Gradient" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5"
        fx="0.35" fy="0.35">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
 
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"
      fill="url(#Gradient)" />

  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="transparent" stroke="white" stroke-width="1"/>
  <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="2" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="2" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
  <text x="38" y="40" fill="white" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt">(fx,fy)</text>
  <text x="63" y="63" fill="white" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt">(cx,cy)</text>
</svg>
```

(example taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fx), fixed slightly and tweaked)

However, if the focal point is *outside* the boundary shape, you end up with something more like a cone:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="Gradient" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5"
        fx="0.05" fy="0.05">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
 
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"
      fill="url(#Gradient)" />

  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="transparent" stroke="white" stroke-width="1"/>
  <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="2" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="2" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
  <text x="28" y="30" fill="white" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt">(fx,fy)</text>
  <text x="63" y="63" fill="white" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt">(cx,cy)</text>
</svg>
```

Notice that it still takes the circle and "shrinks" it down towards the focal point, but because the focal point is now outside the circle, it cannot define any meaningful colour for the points outside the cone.

---

You move the focal point with `fx` and `fy`. There is also `fr` which is useful sometimes but ignore it for now; you can do the same with colour stop positions anyway.

You move the circle with `cx`, `cy` and `r`.

Moving both has the effect of just translating the gradient.

---

Repeat makes this a bit more confusing, but maybe this demo will clarify:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="Gradient" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.3"
        fx="0.4" fy="0.4" spreadMethod="repeat">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
 
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"
      fill="url(#Gradient)" />

  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="30" fill="transparent" stroke="white" stroke-width="1"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="2" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="2" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
  <text x="38" y="40" fill="white" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt">(fx,fy)</text>
  <text x="63" y="63" fill="white" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt">(cx,cy)</text>
</svg>
```

The white circle still defines the shape, so for an intuitive result, the focal point should be inside it.

---

In the example you posted, the gradient itself is very small; occupying just a 10-pixel radius around the centre. It defines a single colour transition. The striped effect is due to the `repeat` option. Here's your example with the focal point and outer shape illustrated:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:lang="en"xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
   <title>Bulls-eye Repeating Radial Gradient</title>
   <radialGradient id="bullseye"cx="50%" cy="50%" r="10%" spreadMethod="repeat">
     <stop stop-color="tomato" offset="50%"/>
     <stop stop-color="#222" offset="50%"/>
  </radialGradient>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#bullseye)"/>
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="10%" fill="transparent" stroke="white" stroke-width="1"/>
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="2" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
</svg>
```

and here's your second example (focal point shown in black this time for clarity):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:lang="en"xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
   <title>Bulls-eye Repeating Radial Gradient</title>
   <radialGradient id="bullseye"cx="50%" cy="50%" fx=".2" fy=".2" r="10%" spreadMethod="repeat">
     <stop stop-color="tomato" offset="50%"/>
     <stop stop-color="#222" offset="50%"/>
  </radialGradient>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#bullseye)"/>
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="10%" fill="transparent" stroke="white" stroke-width="1"/>
  <circle cx="20%" cy="20%" r="2" fill="black" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```